# Removing .html on RewriteRule does not work

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to remove the .html from the URL from the rule below but I get a Internal Server Error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /folder/index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

I want `http://localhost/folder/page.html` to be `http://localhost/folder/page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /folder/index.php?s=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hey pixeline, tried it but didn't work. I also removed .html but didn't worked too.

Comment: Do you actually have mod_rewrite installed on the server?